# Initializing a value through a Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, literals

I need to Initialize a value in a Javascript by using a c# literal that makes reference to a Session Variable. I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" > 
    var myIndex = <%= !((Session["myIndex"]).Equals(null)||(Session["myIndex"]).Equals("")) ? Session["backgroundIndex"] : "1" %>;
```

However the code above is giving me a classic `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. Why? Shouldn't `(Session["myIndex"]).Equals(null)` capture this particular error?

Comment: Session["myIndex"] returns null, and null does not have an .Equals() function. You need to compare with ==, as that is not a function that needs an object to derive from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work (I have tested it!):

```
var myIndex = <%=!string.IsNullOrEmpty( (string)Session["myIndex"] ) ? Session["myIndex"] : "1" %> ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `null` isn't an object, and the `Equals()` method can only be used on objects. If you want to check if your Session object is null, you should use `(Session["myIndex"] == null)`. You can also use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for an additional check on empty strings. In that case, your code should be:

```
var myIndex = <%= !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["myIndex"]) ? Session["backgroundIndex"] : "1" %>;
```

**Note:** Shouldn't `Session["backgroundIndex"]` be `Session["myIndex"]` in this case? Otherwise the  null or empty string check is a bit useless in my opinion.

Comment: -1 for you also... you cannot just do a *string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["myIndex"])* - it won't even compile as *Session[key]* returns an object, not a string. Your explanation was good though.

Comment: @slugster: From the context of the sample, it's clear that `Session["myIndex"]` is a string. If it is a different object, then you might as well let the exception be thrown, because you are not expecting it. Besides, the provided sample doesn't check for strings either.

Comment: I agree the sample doesn't check for (or cast to) strings either. It doesn't matter what is held at that particular index, it is returned as type *object*. At the time i downvoted there were 4 answers, yours was the best but with syntactic errors. If you edit the post i will reverse my downvote.

Comment: Adding a cast to string is a good idea in this case, so I've updated my sample.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `Session["myIndex"]` isn't null?

You should add another short circuit OR check for `(Session["myIndex"] == null)` and get rid of `(Session["myIndex"]).Equals(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

object reference error may be because (Session["myIndex"]) is null,

(Session["myIndex"]).Equals is used to compare value so you can use it you want to compare like (Session["myIndex"]).Equals("yourIndex")

Answer (score -3):

in the code behind create a protected variable and initialize it there. The main advantage is that you can debug it there. And in plus you can use try catch.

code-behind

```
protected string sessionValue;
private void Page_Load(...)
{
try
{
sessionValue = Session["key"].ToString();
}
catch
{
sessionValue = [defaultValue];
}
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
var sessionValue = "<%= sessionValue %>";
</script>
```

This way you can avoid the crash and do something else if the sessionValue is null or has a defaultValue.

Comment: -1 I would not be using try/catch as a substitute for a simple *if (Session["key"] == null)* check.... i hope you don't use that method too often?

Comment: the idea behind try catch is that you can avoid a crash, with if each time the session expires you'll get a crash. Even if i'm not that experienced i believe that this is the safest way to do this.

If you could avoid a crash by doing a simple if check then it's okay, but if there is the slightest possibility that the application could crash i suggest the safer try catch version

Comment: Nope, the page will not crash if the Session expires - you simply get a fresh Session with nothing in it. Stick with the *if null* check, and never make the assumption that your item has been correctly placed into Session.

Comment: thanks for the advice...
If it is not a valuable information that you need to put on the session you can try using request parameters or using a hidden field for storing that string(if it can be converted to a string).